# "Data at the Root Level is invalid" with LoadXml

Tags: c#, xml

I have a code snippet :

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
try
{
    doc.LoadXml(xmlPath);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string exMessage = ex.Message; 
}
```

The XML looks like this

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <MimeTypes>
   <MimeType>
     <Extension>.3dm</Extension>
     <Value>x-world/x-3dmf</Value>
   </MimeType>
  </MimeTypes>
```

Its producing this error:

Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use doc.Load(xmlPath).  LoadXML is for loading an XML string.

Answer (score 3):

You're passing a file path to a parameter that should contain the XML itself.

Answer (score 1):

does *xmlPath* contains the whole xml or a path to a file that contains it? The *LoadXml* method expects the actual XML, not a path to a file. If you want to load the xml using a path, using the *Load* method.